# Kafka metrics not produced when running Flink in AWS Kinesis Analytics

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-kafka, apache-flink, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-kinesis-analytics

I have an Flink application which produces Kafka messages. To do so, I use the [Apache Kafka connector](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/connectors/kafka.html).

This application is running using [AWS Kinesis Analytics](https://aws.amazon.com/kinesis/data-analytics/).
The application is running smoothly and the messages are successfully produced to the Kafka topic.

Anyway I would like to monitor the Kafka metrics from the Flink application. Unfortunately, **there is no kafka metrics appearing in AWS CloudWatch**.

Any idea what could be the reason ?

Comment: What kind of Kafka metrics that you interested to see from your Kinesis Analytics flink application? (Please narrow down your metrics name). Which Kafka are you using? (Vanilla open source or MSK or Confluent Kafka)

Comment: @JayaAnanthram I'm interested to all Kafka producer metrics such as "record-send-rate", see docs here : https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#producer_sender_monitoring

I'm not sure which Kafka, I'm not maintaining it. But most likely MSK or Vanilla open source. Could the server make a different when producing kafka metrics ?